# Finite/non-finite clauses

Tags: verbs, clauses

If the word "was" comes before an -ing verb, for example in "while he was sleeping", is this a finite or non-finite clause and why?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain what arguments you think there are for either option, and why you cannot decide between the two. That way we can address those specific questions.

Answer (score 1):

[Nonfinite clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-finite_clause) contains nonfinite verb form(s) and no finite verb form(s).

However there seems to be no good, crosslinguistically universal definition of nonfinite verb form. <sub>(Current definition in [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonfinite_verb) is garbage, as partially discussed in [talk page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Nonfinite_verb).)</sub>

In English, something like *is sleeping* or *has slept*, as a whole is finite and can be considered to be a form of a compound tense, and consists of finite form of auxiliary verb and nonfinite form (some participle) of another verb.

Examples of nonfinite verbs or clauses:

- *sleeping*
- *while sleeping*

Examples of finite verbs or clauses:

- *was sleeping*
- *is sleeping*
- *will be sleeping*
- *while he was sleeping*
- *while he is sleeping*
- *while he will be sleeping*

Comment: There seems to be no good?

Comment: @Lambie If you want to try to write a definition, then some notes: Japanese and Korean verbs have no inflection for number and person at all (in Japanese, I would consider e.g. 連用形 and *-te* forms to be nonfinite); Latin and Ancient Greek verbs have infinitives for several tenses (Latin for present, perfect and future); Lithuanian verbs have [participles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithuanian_grammar#Participles) for several tenses (present, past, future).

Comment: Why are you discussing cross-linguistic non-finite forms? The question was about English. Also, you might want to state clearly the difference between finite and non-finite clauses...

Comment: @Lambie how do you know the question is about English? OP didn’t say that. /troll

Comment: @Keelan Because the OP references only English forms, not German, not French, not Icelandic, and not any other **natural language**. Troll, indeed.